# VisualForce page - multi-select being rendered without the buttons

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select

I have a multi-select input field on my VF page, it is based on a field defined as **mult-select** in the custom object (Data Type  is `Picklist (Multi-Select)`).

```
<td class="RightColumnTop W80" style="height:auto !important;">
    <div class="Mandatory">  
        <apex:inputField styleClass="MainPanelFont" 
            style="height:auto !important;width: auto !important;" 
            value="{!sObjectRFC.Benefits_Reasons__c }"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

In one page (Edit) the fields render correctly as two select lists with buttons in between:

[image]

but on another page, *even though the code is the same* they render without the buttons in between:

[image]

so what could be causing this on IE11, but we have the same issue on FireFox

any suggestions on how to resolve that?

At the top of our two pages we have this defined:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Comment: The fields are grayed out-- it appears they're read-only, which would imply that the UI is indeed correct. Perhaps it's a difference in user permissions?

Comment: @sfdcfox: no in fact that's the `<styleClass="MainPanelFont">` setting the text color and font... no issues with user permissions either, as it allows me to double-click an item to choose it

Comment: the second screen shot has the caption "(Double click an item to select it)" - is this a clue?

Comment: @crop1645: well, I've added that as a workaround for the users in case I cannot get it to render properly... right now I am seriously considering rebuilding the entire page from the ground up step by step to see what works...

Comment: Try To Move The Left Box. Sometimes Box Hide The Buttons. I Have Also Face Same Issue.

Comment: @OurManInBananas did your problem solved?

Comment: @TusharSharma: no, no luck yet, I've tried moving it to the left, it's truly annoying!

Comment: The only way to fix this was to copy from the *Edit* page where it was working - must have been something strange on the *New* page ...